# Taking mongoengine.connect out of the setting.py in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

Most of the blog posts and examples on the web, in purpose of connecting to the MongoDB using Mongoengine in Python/Django, have suggested that we should add these lines to the `settings.py` file of the app:

```
from mongoengine import connect
connect('project1', host='localhost')
```

It works fine for most of the cases except one I have faced recently:
When the database is down!

Let say if db goes down, the process that is taking care of the web server (in my case, `Supervisord`) will stop running the app because of Exception that `connect` throws. It may try few more times but after its timeout reached, it will stop trying.

So even if your app has some parts that are not tied to db, they will also break down.

A quick solution to this is adding a try/exception block to the connect code:

```
try:
    connect('project1', host='localhost')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

but I am looking for a better and clean way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not really possible with `mongoengine` unless you go with the `try-except` solution like you did.

You could try to connect with pure `pymongo` version 3.0+ using `MongoClient` and registering the connection manually in the `mongoengine.connection._connection_settings` dictionary (quite hacky but should work). From [pymongo documentation](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient):

> Changed in version 3.0: MongoClient is now the one and only client class for a standalone server, mongos, or replica set. It includes the functionality that had been split into MongoReplicaSetClient: it can connect to a replica set, discover all its members, and monitor the set for stepdowns, elections, and reconfigs.
>
> **The MongoClient constructor no longer blocks while connecting to the server or servers, and it no longer raises ConnectionFailure if they are unavailable, nor ConfigurationError if the user’s credentials are wrong**. Instead, the constructor returns immediately and launches the connection process on background threads.

Comment: FYI, mongoengine provides a method for [registering a connection](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.register_connection). But I'm still confused that how and where I should connect to db in this scenario (either using pymongo or mongoengine)? should I write a middleware? :-/

Comment: Yes it does, but I'm not sure if you will be able to use it. How to connect - use `pymongo` and register connection with `mongoengine`. As for where - usually on the application startup, definitly settings are not the place for it, but I'm no django expert, so you may have ask a separate question for that.